# Apply gradient on image

Tags: css, image, gradient

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj7mgrb1/1/).

I have an transformed image and I would like to add a gradient (black to transparant) on it.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="contentwrap">
  <div class="perspectiveDiv">
      <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/34/1408372755-black-card.png"  class="img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.contentwrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    padding-top: 150px;
}

.perspectiveDiv{
    perspective:750px; 
    position: relative; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;    
}

.img{
    position: absolute; 
    top: -152px;  
    left: 25px;
    transform:  rotateX(60deg); 
    max-width: 250px;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);;
    box-shadow: 0 60px 45px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Here is the kind of result that I need (made with photoshop) :

[image]

I found how to apply a gradient on a background image, but not a standard image...

Is it possible to do what I need ?

Can you help me to do it ? It could be very simple but I'm a beginner and I didn't manage to do it...

Comment: Impossible with pure CSS.

Comment: You could have two superposed `div` at the same position, one with background image, and the other with the css gradient. And each with `opacity:0.5` for example

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers. So I'll simply add another image with only the gradient on top of the other....